# Segfault in constructor, but only with certain template arguments

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, constructor, segmentation-fault

I'm trying to write a little helper class for drawing a mandelbrot fractal. The class `Canvas` has two two-dimensional arrays, one for storing the coordinates of the complex plane and one for the number of iterations needed to get `|z|` over 2.

The template arguments specify the width and the hight of the canvas in pixels. Now the funny thing is, everything works fine with arguments to  
 `<500, 500>`, but if I choose for example `<600, 600>` I get a segmentation fault. I already checked and out-of-bounds error by using `array.at()` instead of `array[]` but still nothing.

```
template <std::size_t W, std::size_t H>
class Canvas
{
public:
    Canvas(std::complex<double> _origin, std::complex<double> _end);
    ...


private:
    std::complex<double> origin;
    std::complex<double> end;
    std::array<std::array<std::complex<double>, H>, W> field;
    std::array<std::array<std::pair<bool, int>, H>, W> results;
};


template <std::size_t W, std::size_t H>
Canvas<W, H>::Canvas(std::complex<double> _origin, 
                     std::complex<double> _end)
    : origin{_origin}, end{_end}
{
    double delta_x {end.real() - origin.real()};
    double delta_y {end.imag() - origin.imag()};
    double step_x {delta_x / static_cast<double>(W-1)};
    double step_y {delta_y / static_cast<double>(H-1)};

    for (std::size_t w = 0; w < W; ++w)
    {
        for (std::size_t h = 0; h < H; ++h)
        {
            field[w][h].real(origin.real() + (step_x*w));
            field[w][h].imag(origin.imag() + (step_y*h));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: where is the segfault occuring? can you mark the line with a comment?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know the exact line, just that it's inside the constructor.

Comment: you can use a debugger to find the line.

Comment: The object for which you call the constructor, it is not by any chance allocated on the stack (aka automatic storage)? Because, ya know, it's huge...

Comment: Where do you create an instance of `Canvas` on heap or on the stack?

Comment: Thank you, that's it. Allocating it on the heap works fine.
But I don't really see, where it gets that big. Should only be a couple of MBs or not?

Comment: @simnale Just say your comment after I wrote my answer. You can check the size with `sizeof()`, of course, but "a couple MBs" is something I would even avoid putting on the stack by habbit. You might consult you OS manuals to find out how big a stack is allowed in your environment.

Comment: `cout << sizeof(Canvas)` might be enlightening... Your `field` member is an array of `complex<double>` which is likely to be 16 bytes per element, and `results` is likely to be 8 bytes per element - 24 bytes per element * 600 * 600 is around 8.6MB, which is quite large for stack-based allocation. I'm actually surprised the 500x500 case worked (6MB)... I would guess your system/compiler combination provides an 8MB stack...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have run the code and it seems that what you get is stack overflow (ironic).
You can see that because it fails at:

```
; Find next lower page and probe

cs20:
        sub     eax, _PAGESIZE_         ; decrease by PAGESIZE
        test    dword ptr [eax],eax     ; probe page. <------ HERE
        jmp     short cs10
```

You can also see this by the fact that it starts failing after some point, after the numbers staring to get large and allocating it on the heap fixes the problem.
Your Canvas object is that huge because of:

```
std::array<std::array<std::complex<double>, H>, W> field;
std::array<std::array<std::pair<bool, int>, H>, W> results;
```

Both of size `H * W * sizeof(complex<double>)` or `H * W * sizeof(pair<bool,int>)`.
I suggest you simply use this class on the heap and don't allocate it on the stack when using high template numbers (for 400, 400 it failed for me already).

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem might be that you allocate the instance of `Canvas` on the stack. If you have something like this:

```
void f()
{
    std::complex<double> origin( 0, 0 );
    std::complex<double> end( 100, 100 );

    Canvas< 600, 600 > cv( origin, end );
    // ...
}
```

You might need to check if allocating the object on the heap helps:

```
void f()
{
    std::complex<double> origin( 0, 0 );
    std::complex<double> end( 100, 100 );

    typedef Canvas< 600, 600 > CV
    auto cv_ptr = std::unique_ptr< CV >( new CV( origin, end ) );
    // ...
}
```